# Ajax Success to Refresh Cart Contents on Shopify Capital Theme

Tags: ajax, shopify, cart

I  have been trying to update the cart drawer using my upsell product button. I have added product variant add to cart button in the cart drawer liquid code, which is using ajax cart to add the item to cart drawer but i am not sure what to put in success of the ajax request i am making.

here's my example code, please let me know what should I put in the success so it refreshes the cart drawer contents upon success. website address is: https://sailpak.myshopify.com/

```
       $('#cart-btn-2').click(function(){    
                addItemToCart2( 41162793713847, 1);
      });
        
      function addItemToCart2(variant_id, qty) {
        
        
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/cart/add.js',
          data: {
          id: variant_id,
          quantity: qty
        },
          dataType: 'json',
              success: // what to put here so cart contents refresh with newly added item
      })
      }
```

thanks

Comment: your theme have already a update cart function into JS you need to check code and call it properly to work with your custom code.

Comment: I tried finding the code and then using the updatecartdrawer function I found but it's not helping update the cart drawer contents.

Answer (score 0):

Some premium themes have a refresh cart object that you can call to, but most themes don't.
Try to check your theme's script if it has one, if not, then you have to get content from the cart using their API and re-render contents to the DOM.